# AfterEffect. Arrow with stationary origin, moving head

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects, path-effects, arrow

need help animating an arched arrow in adobe after effect. Here is an animation “draft” of what type of movement i need to create:
[image]
or you can download a video here.
[animation draft](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/727238150229065840/823960646123126844/2021-03-23_18.29.41.mp4)

That is:
The origin of the arrow stays static, but the arrow head moves along a path. And the arrow is not straight but curved just like in the linked video.

P.s. any linke to the youtube videos or articles would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: http://video.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Video editing questions are [off-topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.  Sorry about that. Please post in Video Production Stack Exchange instead, or flag your question and ask a mod to migrate it for you.